# Firestore SnapshotListener stops updating data when using multiple criteria

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a repository in my SwiftUI app that grabs all actions for a particular user from Google Cloud Firestore. It uses a Snapshot Listener to keep the action list up to date.

I wanted to change the query to limit results to actions that weren't already completed, by adding this line to my code:

```
.whereField("completed", isEqualTo: false)
```

And here is the function it was added to, that creates the listener and sets it to the "actions" variable in the repository:

```
    func loadData() {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        if userId != nil {
            self.listener = db.collection("action")
                .order(by: "createdTime")
                .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId!)
                .whereField("completed", isEqualTo: false)
                .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                        self.actions = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                            do {
                                let x = try document.data(as: Action.self)
                                return x
                            }
                            catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
```

But once I added that (I have an index for userId, but not for completed, if that matters), it loads data correctly the first time, but the view does not get updated when I add or change existing actions, until I quit and reopen the app.

Is there any issue with having multiple criteria like this for a Snapshot listener? Or anything else that would be causing this listener to not get dynamic updates any more?

Comment: You need to handle the returned `error` before you check if querySnapshot is nil. e.g. if your rules prevent reading you won't know about it. In this case an error is being returned *Listen for query at action failed: The query requires an index. You can create it here:* and it then provides a link to create the required index.

Comment: If the view is properly updated on app restart then it cannot be an index problem. That said, you should always print errors while building an application because as Jay said, if there is an index error it will prompt you with a link that creates one for you. Show the code where you update the view with this data because that is where the problem is.

Comment: Hey @Jay my error handling knowledge is not that great, but I do print the error, and I missed that one in the output. I do see that now. It was showing an index error - I thought it shouldn't because I just had two equality operators, but it appears it's because I was also including the "order" method in there. The composite index it's suggesting includes "createdTime" in addition to "userId" and "completed." Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create composite indexes for multiple queries

[How to create compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0)

You can read the compound queries section of firebase documentation.
Creating compund queries requires some time..

Comment: Looks like this is correct. According to the firebase documentation, I didn't think I would need to for multiple equality operators in the same query. But I think it's because I add the ".order" method to order the data that it requires a composite index.

Comment: @Charlie That is correct - the `.order` requires the indexes to be generated.